# Spring Boot with Custom Converters breaks Swagger & how to move it

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a very simple Spring Boot application.  I launch this through the basic `SpringApplication.run(Startup.class, args);` and have a custom `@Configuration` class in there that overrides the default converters.  I decided to add [Swagger](http://swagger.io) to the mix of things so that I can generate better documentation for our internal user base as there are gads of endpoints.

When I started things up, Swagger simply wouldn't work.

I decided to start a front-scratch Spring Boot with just one endpoint to document to see what went wrong.  **Out-of-the box this worked perfectly fine** and I was able to get Swagger running via just hitting the http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html base URL.

When I implemented my custom `@Configuration` class that extended `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, Swagger no longer worked.

My configuration overrode a single method:

```
@Configuration
public class StartupConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(getJsonConverter());
  }
}
```

That's it.  I decided to add the default converters as well without any luck.  Then I just emptied the class and left it as:

```
@Configuration
public class StartupConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
}
```

Swagger is still broken - if I **remove the class completely**, then it works.

What can I do to keep my custom configuration data and run Swagger?  I would also love to move it to something like http://localhost:8080/swagger/ rather than the default file it uses, but that is a completely separate issue for now.

My launch of Swagger looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Docket getDocket() {
    // ...
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .groupName("Core API")
      .apiInfo(infoBuilder.build())
      .select().paths(PathSelectors.regex("/*"))
      .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: You may consider generating spring boot based on openapi/swagger spec instead: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO#java-springboot

Comment: @dunni no error messages besides the 404 (including in the console log)

Comment: @eln00b Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @ElliotVargas not completely, no.  I wound up completely resetting how I did things instead.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the default resource handler worked for me. I added the following to the configuration class extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```